# why Chromedriver is not working?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to start with selenium, but getting error. Checked a lot on web for resolution, but no luck. Please check

Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class Webdriver_class {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\selenium_java\\chromedriver.exe");
           WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

                  driver.get("http://google.com");

                  System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

                  driver.close();

    }

}
```

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.findExecutable(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:87)
    at Webdriver_class.main(Webdriver_class.java:11)
```

My Dependencies:
[image]

Comment: Did you add the dependencies ? http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
Download java one. Let me know for further Issue.

Comment: Hi, getting new error now. Updated in original question.

Comment: which version of `selenium-java` you are using?

Comment: version i am using is 2.0b1

Comment: How did you run the above class ?

Comment: And Use TestNG or JUnit to run your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing the Selenium Server dependency because that one should contain `org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker`

Comment: Hi, getting new error now. Updated in original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine , i tested it. Please make sure you have java specific Selenium bindings included in your project.

Please download them from below location and make sure you include all.

[http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGIGf.png)
[image]

Comment: Added snapshot of my dependencies. It's not working. :(

Comment: I hope you are able to run 'hello world! ' program??

Answer (score 0):

I use this below dependency in my code , that is works with google chrome. You download this jar may be it will works for you.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Download **selenium-java 2.53 jar**.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem as I had imported multiple versions of selenium-java jars of different versions. Kept one, removed others, worked like a charm!